# Selecting Columns to fill based on numbers of items in row

Tags: pandas

So I have 4 columns in a dataframe: W, X, Y, Z.

I have a CSV file that has some rows with some having 4 items, 3 items, and 2 items per row.

I am using:

```
frame = pd.read_csv("file_example.csv", names = [ 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

Is there a way to make it so that the rows with 3 fill in W X and Z skipping over Y and leaving then NAN? And similarly make it so that the rows with 2 items fill in W and Z, skipping over X and Y? As it is now it just fills in the first columns it comes across.

In other words, is there a way to pick and choose which columns a row will fill up based on the number of items in the row?

Thanks.

Edit: 
Input (corresponding to the output):

```
2,seafood,21418

2,stews,24126

2,seafood,23287

2,sandwiches,17429
```

and

```
4,6237

4,30815

4,5321

4,49248
```

Trying the method below, I put 100 test lines each of 4,3,2 item rows.
Sample part of output:

3 item line:

```
 2     seafood     21418.0  21418

 2       stews     24126.0  24126

 2     seafood     23287.0  23287

 2  sandwiches     17429.0  17429
```

2 item line:

```
 4        6237         NaN   6237

 4        30815         NaN  30815

 4        5321         NaN   5321

 4       49248         NaN  49248
```

The z is filling correctly, but the NaNs are not masking over.

Edit 2: Did not assign the new dataframe to a variable. Solution works.

Comment: CSV structure is clear so I don't think you can do it with read_csv but it sure is possible with postprocessing. Can you post a sample of your CSV file?

Comment: Sure, so an example would be (The columns are ID, Name, Date, Number) and the csv file would have some row of:
`10,Blue,20160809,203   
12,Red,20160810,4578   
9,Red,3094
15,Yellow,109    
1,86    
5,9384     
56,3490`    

Sorry for the wonky formatting,I'm new, but some rows would have 4,3, and 2 parameters only but they correspond to certain columns in the dataframe, with the others being blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])
df
```

```
Out: 
    W       X           Y       Z
0  10    Blue  20160809.0   203.0
1  12     Red  20160810.0  4578.0
2   9     Red      3094.0     NaN
3  15  Yellow       109.0     NaN
4   1      86         NaN     NaN
5   5    9384         NaN     NaN
6  56    3490         NaN     NaN
```

Record the positions of NaNs:

```
nans = df.isnull().values
```

Fill Z column:

```
df['Z'] = df['Z'].fillna(df['Y'].fillna(df['X']))
```

Shift NaNs to the left:

```
df.mask(np.roll(nans, -1), np.nan)
```

```
Out: 
    W       X           Y     Z
0  10    Blue  20160809.0   203
1  12     Red  20160810.0  4578
2   9     Red         NaN  3094
3  15  Yellow         NaN   109
4   1     NaN         NaN    86 
5   5     NaN         NaN  9384
6  56     NaN         NaN  3490
```

Comment: Hey, one more thing, I tried doing it on my machine, and for me filling Z column works, but filling in NaN for X and Y seem to be not working, it will end up something like this for 2 item rows:

395  4       35379         NaN  35379
396  4        1064         NaN   1064
397  4       46717         NaN  46717
398  4        4119         NaN   4119
399  4       26060         NaN  26060

And this for 3 item rows:
156  2  sandwiches     30517.0  30517
157  2  sandwiches     39551.0  39551
158  2     cereals     48378.0  48378

So it will fill but not NaN out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that output? Please also post the corresponding CSV lines. It is very hard to read them in the comments.

Comment: Can you also add the actual CSV lines which created that output?

Comment: Yes, added it   @@@

Comment: Are you assigning the last line to a variable? (`df = df.mask(np.roll(nans, -1), np.nan)`) It returns a new dataframe so if you don't save it the original dataframe will remain unchanged. With the input you provided I tested again it seems to work.

Comment: Exactly my mistake. You are the best.

Comment: Thanks. Keep in mind that almost all operations in pandas, unless you explicitly use `inplace=True`, return a new dataframe.